# WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-5.11.0) - Error 405 - Method Not Allowed on Password Reset via Recovery Email

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2is-5.11.0 and I'm trying to apply password reset via recovery email.
I followed the below documentation.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/forced-password-reset/#password-reset-via-recovery-email

[image: Password Reset]

Once I set the Force Password Reset claim true for a certain profile, the password reset link is received properly via email. The link redirects properly for the password reset form as well and once the new password is entered and confirmed it redirects to the following error page.

[image: 405 Method Not Allowed]

A valid solution to resolve this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when trying the flow, open the network tab of the browser and see what the HTTP method invoked for `https://<host>:<port>/myaccount&passwordReset=true`
It should be a GET request.
[image]

405 method not allowed will be occurred if the invoked HTTP method is not supported in the myaccount application/ if the myaccount is not functioning properly in your setup.

The response of GET `https://<host>:<port>/myaccount&passwordReset=true` is a redirection to the management console `https://<host>:<port>/carbon/admin/login.jsp`.

Anyway redirecting the password reseted user to management console doesn't make much sense. They might want to log into the myaccount / any other business application.

If you want to redirected a successfully password reset user to myaccount :

1. Go to `<IS-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/accountrecoveryendpoint/password-reset-complete.jsp`
2. remove the `&passwordReset=true` query param in this line.
   `location.href = "<%= IdentityManagementEndpointUtil.getURLEncodedCallback(callback)%>&passwordReset=true";`

If you want to redirect the successful password reset user to another application, change the link given in the email template "AdminForcedPasswordReset" providing the query param `callback=<URL encoded URL to redirect`

Comment: Thanks. I did this, but now I am getting an error page with "Error! Server failed to respond."

Comment: Following could be seen in the log. TID: [-1234] [accountrecoveryendpoint] [2023-09-25 12:48:07,469] [af78eb4e-5d6c-4ecc-8adb-4ade459dcfa6] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/accountrecoveryendpoint].[completepasswordreset.do]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [completepasswordreset.do] in context with path [/accountrecoveryendpoint] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [password-reset-complete.jsp] at line [94]
Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1